# How to prevent stack overflow in a game that infinitely loops?

Tags: c++

I made a Tetris game in c++ command line. It actually works perfectly fine until the stack overflows. I understand what a stack overflow is, but I don't know how to prevent it in a game that is supposed to go on forever. For sake of not sharing 700+ lines of code, I am going to simplify the code into basic functions.

Code:

```
int main(){
    //Sets position of first block
    //picks random tetris piece for player to control
    updateScreenMain();
}
int updateScreenMain(){
    //All code related to drawing screen is here
    //At the end of it, there are several if statments-
    //-that test for if the block hit the ground yet
    // If one of those functions is called, example: reseting the 
    // block to the top of the screen, it will call updateScreenMain() 
    // again
}
```

Basically, what I want to do is clear the stack memory. I see that when my functions call other functions, they get nested until a stack overflow. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Use a loop instead of recursion - recursion is absolutely not the right tool for this

Comment: Rather use something like `for(;;)` or `while(true)` instead of recursion.

Comment: If you really must use recursion make sure it's tail recursion so the compiler can optimise away your function calls. Tail recursive code is usually easy to convert to a loop. If you want us to help further we need a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks guys I just turned everything into one huge loop and it seemed to do the trick

Comment: You say in your title that you want something that "infinitely ***loops***". That should have been a hint about the solution. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways. Here is an example:

```
int main() {
    while(updateScreenMain());
}
int updateScreenMain() {
    // Just return 0 to stop
}
```

In general, just avoid recursion.